# Parcelable in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In Android there are `Parcelable` and `Serializable`, and
`Parcelable` is faster than `Serializable`.
Is there a equivalent of `Parcelable` in C#/.NET?

Comment: `Parcelable` is faster than `Serializable` in Java because `Serializable` in Java is notoriously slow - maybe look into what serialization options are actually available in C# and benchmark them instead of trying to port your code 1-to-1?

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of things, it is only available in the Xamarin `Android.OS` namespace: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.os.parcelable?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9). Serializable is what you will have to use in any other C# .NET project.